# ramas en diferentes commit

Tags: git, git-push

Creo que el repositorio está  descontrolado y desorganizado.
Debería tener solo el repositorio remoto y el local. Al darle
`git push origin master` salta el siguiente error:

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/
> hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
> hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
> hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.'

Traté de solucionarlo pero no he logrado que funcione.
Necesito que las ramas estén en el Head que es por donde va el proyecto.
Gracias!

[image: Repositorio GIT actualizado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese mensaje es bastante claro. La rama a la que estás tratando de empujar, en el remoto ya tiene unos cambios que tú no tienes en la rama local lo que haría que esos cambios en el remoto se perdieran. Por el gráfico que colocaste se puede ver que la posición de `origin/master` es parte de la historia de `HEAD`, lo que significa que no estás actualizado con respecto a lo que hay en el remoto. Tienes que hacer un `git fetch` para obtener información actualizada. De cualquier forma, en general hay 3 opciones:

- Haces fetch/merge (o un pull *normalón*, es lo mismo) de la rama remota para incluir los cambios en tu rama. Con eso ya tendrías todos los cambios de la rama remota y git te dejaría empujar.
- Haces un fetch/rebase sobre la rama remota. De nuevo, con eso ya tendrías todos los cambios de la rama remota y git te dejaría empujar.
- Si no te interesa mantener los cambios que estén en el remoto y quieres dejar la rama tal cual la tienes en tu local, tienes que hacer un `git push -f` para que funcione. Cuando git haga el push te va a decir el ID de la revisión que estaba antes en el remoto, por si acaso.... pero en general no es buena idea, a menos que sepas lo que estás haciendo.

Si lo que quieres hacer es lo que dices (forzar `HEAD`, sin importar más nada), puedes hacer esto:

```
git push origin -f HEAD:master
```

Para poner lo que tienes en `HEAD` en la rama `master` remota.

Comment: Intenté el fetch y el pull, pero me dice que todo está correcto y no hay nada que actualizar. Si hago un push origin HEAD:hash me hace el push, pero debería hacerlo solo con el push. Además, tengo (master) en un commit muy abajo, y otro commit tiene un hash también. Creo que no supe hacerlo, bien, podrías especifcarme un poco mas el proceso?.

Comment: Ya me funcionó. No estaba haciendo bien el pull. Lo hacía desde el head, y tenía que ser desde el Master. Solucionado. Gracias!

Comment: Ok... no había visto tus respuestas. El pull sin parámetros te va a funcionar si estás en una rama. Como estabas trabajando en **detached HEAD**, no funciona y por eso tienes que especificar lo que quieres halar.... o trabajar desde una rama